# Syncfusion GroupingGrid always expanded

Tags: syncfusion

I´m working with a GroupingGrid of the Syncfusion. And I realized that the ExpandAllGroups() operation is consuming many resources, than I thought that maybe GroupingGrid have some parameter that lets all groups expanded by default. 
Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative way to expand the Groups is by using `IsExpanded` property. This is a `Boolean` property which could be set to `true` in order to set the groups to an expanded state.

```
public void iterate(Group g)
{
    foreach (Group gr in g.Groups)
    {
        gr.IsExpanded = true;
        iterate(gr);
    }
}
```

The above method can be called by using the following code in form():

```
this.iterate(this.gridGroupingControl1.Table.TopLevelGroup);
```

Kindly, check with the above code and see if it resolves your issue